# Generate Qt treeview item and select it for editing by the user

Tags: qt, treeview

In a Qt application I want to create a treeview item (QStandardItem for a QStandardItemModel) and immediately select it for editing. As if the user double clicked on it.

How?

Answer (score 0):

I just found it...

```
QStandardItem *parentItem = m_model->invisibleRootItem();
QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem("new file");
item->setEditable(true);
parentItem->appendRow(item);
ui->treeView->edit(item->index());
```